# cannot run java while adding .jar

Tags: java, javac

I have a java class (ts3.java) and i`m using teamspeak3.jar for a project . 
In ts3.java i'm importing :

```
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.TS3Api;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.TS3Config;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.TS3Query;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.TextMessageTargetMode;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.TS3EventAdapter;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.TS3EventType;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.TextMessageEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
```

and compile using `javac -cp teamspeak3.jar ts3.java` and works perfectly

When i try to run `java -cp .:./teamspeak3.jar ts3` it sais : `Error: Could not find or load main class ts3`

I'm trying to make it run for 30 minutes now and no success. Tried everything. Please help me. I don't want to put ts3.class in some .com folder and adding package to it.

Comment: can u tell me main method syntax of ts3 class?check it shud be public static void main(String args[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your main class is called `ts3`,
and it is the default package (no package).
Then, verify that `ts3.class` exists in the current directory (`ls ts3.class`).
Because it looks like that's not the case.

If `ts3.class` is in a different directory, or not in the default package (has a `package ...` declaration in it),
then you'll need to adjust the value of the `-cp` parameter and possibly your working directory.

Other things to be careful with:

- The class must be declared public, and have a method with signature `public static void main(String[] args)`
- Class names are case sensitive. If the name is `Ts3`, then it should be in a file `Ts3.class`, and the command should use `Ts3` as the class name to run.
- In Windows, the separator in the classpath is `;` (semicolon), not `:` (colon). So then the value of `-cp` should be something like `.;teamspeak3.jar`

Comment: ts3.class and teamspeak.jar are in the same folder

Comment: And the class is declared `public`, and it has a method with signature `public static void main(String[] args)` right?

Comment: public class Ts3 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

Comment: class names are case sensitive. If the name is `Ts3`, then it should be in a file `Ts3.class`, and your command should be `java -cp .:./teamspeak3.jar Ts3`

Comment: `I:\JAVA\teamspeak>java -cp .:./teamspeak3.jar Ts3`
Error: Could not find or load main class Ts3 - teamspeak3.jar and Ts3.java and Ts3.class are in the same folder.

Comment: So you are in Windows. In Windows, the path separator in the classpath is `;` (semicolon), not `:` (colon). So then the command should be `java -cp .;teamspeak3.jar Ts3`

Comment: Looool . Man u saved my life. I didn't even noticed. Thank you very much

Comment: can i ask you one more question ? how can i import the whole com.* from the jar. if i use `import com.*;` while parsing i have some errors : `Ts3.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                api.registerEvent(TS3EventType.TEXT_CHANNEL, 0);` so i need to import it like this to work : `import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.TS3EventType;`

Comment: That's just how the language works. Wildcards don't span levels, and only work at the last level, importing all classes at that level.